# What is DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST flag?

Tags: docker

I am trying to understand this flag DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1 but not able to figure it out. How does it effect pushing images and pulling images, let's say from docker hub?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/trust/content_trust/